# Chamar uma função depois de validar um formulário no Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou a tentar fazer um exercício que consiste em mostrar uns valores após o utilizador fornecer os dados correctos num formulário. Tentei usar

```
<form class="needs-validation" onsubmit="calcular()" novalidate>
```

Mas apenas limpa os dados do utilizador em vez de fazer a função calcular.

Está aqui o código completo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ctanunes/c1nj2vwd/

Comment: Mas vc quer submeter o formulário ou apenas calcular?

Comment: apenas calcular, mas queria as validações também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas no código que está impedindo de funcionar. Um deles é o botão:

```
<button type="clean" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-3" id="limpar" onclick="limpar()">Limpar</button>
```

Esse `type="clean"` não existe nas especificações HTML. Como é inválido, o botão vai funcionar no padrão `type="submit"`, submetendo o formulário.

Esse `novalidate` invalida os `required`. Como o próprio nome sugere, quer dizer que os campos não precisam ser validados pelo HTML.

Altere o `type` do botão "Limpar" para `button`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-3" id="limpar" onclick="limpar()">Limpar</button>
```

Também remova os `id`s dois dois botões. Ao usar o mesmo nome no `id` de um elemento dentro de um `form` e de uma função, gera conflito. Se não precisa dos `id`s, remova-os ou troque de nome.

No `form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {` creio que apenas o `preventdefault()` seja suficiente, para impedir que o formulário seja submetido.

Na função `limpar()` é preciso também remover a classe `.was-validated` do `form`.

Vamos ver funcionando:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Ficha6</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mt-5 pb-3 font-weight-light">Cálculo de Escalão e IRC</h1>

        <form class="needs-validation" onsubmit="calcular()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomeEmpresa">Insira o nome da empresa</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeEmpresa" placeholder="Nome Empresa" required>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Bom nome!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lucro">Insira o valor do lucro (euros)</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="lucro" min="0" placeholder="Lucro" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    Insira um valor positivo!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lucro">Escalão</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="escalao" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lucro">Taxa de IRC</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taxa" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lucro">Valor imposto (euros)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imposto" readonly>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 mr-3" onclick="limpar()">Limpar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2 float-right">Calcular</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script>
        var escaloes = ["Escalão 1", "Escalão 2", "Escalão 3"];
        var taxa = ["12,5%", "25,0%", "28,0%"];

        function calcular() {

            var lucro = parseInt(document.getElementById("lucro").value);
            if (lucro < 12500) {

                document.getElementById("escalao").value = escaloes[0];
                document.getElementById("taxa").value = taxa[0];
                var irc = lucro * 0.125;
                document.getElementById("imposto").value = irc;

            } else if (lucro < 2000000) {

                document.getElementById("escalao").value = escaloes[1];
                document.getElementById("taxa").value = taxa[1];
                var irc = lucro * 0.25;
                document.getElementById("imposto").value = irc;

            } else {

                document.getElementById("escalao").value = escaloes[2];
                document.getElementById("taxa").value = taxa[2];
                var irc = lucro * 0.28;
                document.getElementById("imposto").value = irc;

            }
        }
        function limpar() {
           var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
           // Loop over them and prevent submission
           var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                form.classList.remove('was-validated');
           });
            var nada = '';
            document.getElementById("escalao").value = nada;
            document.getElementById("taxa").value = nada;
            document.getElementById("imposto").value = nada;
            document.getElementById("nomeEmpresa").value = nada;
            document.getElementById("lucro").value = nada;

        }
        function verlucropositivo() {
            var lucro = parseInt(document.getElementById("lucro").value);
        }
    </script>

    <script>
            // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
            (function () {
                'use strict';
                window.addEventListener('load', function () {
                    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
                    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
                    // Loop over them and prevent submission
                    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
                        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            form.classList.add('was-validated');
                        }, false);
                    });
                }, false);
            })();
    </script>

    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigada pela explicação! Era mesmo isto :)

Answer (score 0):

> Ao anexar o manipulador de eventos ao elemento de formulário, o escopo do manipulador de eventos é o formulário e não a janela.
>
> Como os elementos de entrada dentro de um formulário são anexados como propriedades ao objeto form, onde o nome é a chave, chamar calcular()o manipulador de eventos, onde o escopo é o formulário, seria igual a chamada form.calcular(), mas o formulário já tem um elemento com esse nome form.calcular é o botão de submit, não a calcular() função no escopo global.

Toque o `id`do `button id="btn_calcular"`.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581273/javascript-onsubmit-not-working)

Comment: Infelizmente isso não resolve o problema

Comment: @CatarinaNunes, o que exatamente você quer a função calcular retorne?

Comment: A função calcular muda os valores dentro das caixas do Escalão, Taxa e Valor.

Comment: Veja, a função calcular está a funcionar se fizer a alteração no `id`, entretanto o elemento responsável por exibir o retorno do calculo é `readonly` (apenas leitura), então você precisar acertar essa lógica.